# Curve To Mesh Normals Are Random

Tags: geometry-nodes

[image: Normals Seemingly randomized.]

I want to have the normals all facing the same direction. The path is meant to be complex and go upside down and whatnot so I can't align them to a global direction. I'm not even sure why this is happening since the curve to mesh normals have worked properly before, the project file seems cursed. help.

[image]

Comment: You have a Set Curve Normal node plugged into the profile curve input of the Curve to Mesh node. are you sure you don't want a curve circle or something? Maybe this is not unusual but I think that might be the issue.

Comment: Removing that changes nothing, it was there in an attempt to fix the issue.

Comment: The unpredictable behaviour is because the curve used as a *Profile Curve* is set to *Cyclic*. So sometimes the *Sample Nearest Surface* node is picking the "upper" face, sometimes the "lower" face. In *Edit Mode*, go to menu *Curve/Toggle Cyclic*. It should cure the defect.

Comment: I implemented a temporary fix by adding a 3rd point so that it had some separation. This makes so much sense though! Thank you so much <3